# Question about Failed to reduce the DAE index

Tags: modelica

I just learned the modelica language recently, and I am currently building a mathematical model, using the externalmedia physical property library, and customizing many functions, but the following problems occurred during the running process, how to solve this situation.

```
Failed to differentiate the equation
T = Water.ph.T_ph(Ps, Hs*1000, 0);

in order to reduce the DAE index.

Cannot find differentiation function:
Water.ph.T_ph(Ps, Hs*1000, 0)
with respect to time

Failed to reduce the DAE index.
```

Here are the relevant partial functions, and what I'm guessing is the offending code.

```
  V1*der(Ps)=Rs*T*(Ge+Gaux+Geved-Gvo-Gn)/3600;
  rou2=Water.pT.d_pT(Ps,T,0);
  der(rou2*V1*Hs)=(Ge*He+Gaux*Haux+Geved*h1-Gvo*Hs-Gn*Hs)/3600;
function T_ph
  "Return thermodynamic state as function of p, h and phase"
    extends Modelica.Icons.Function;
    input Water.total.Medium.AbsolutePressure p "Pressure";
    input Water.total.Medium.SpecificEnthalpy h "Enthalpy";
    input Water.total.Medium.FixedPhase phase=0
    "2 for two-phase, 1 for one-phase, 0 if not known";
    output Water.total.Medium.Temperature T;
protected 
       Water.total.Medium.ThermodynamicState state;
algorithm 
  state := Water.total.Medium.setState_ph(
        p,
        h,
        phase);
     T:=state.T;
end T_ph;
function total

package Medium
extends ExternalMedia.Media.CoolPropMedium(
    mediumName = "Water")
end Medium;

end total;
```

Because I used the differentiation of time, I guess that the custom function may not be able to perform related processing, and I don't know how to solve it.
Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: You could supply the derivative to that function, see https://www.claytex.com/blog/applying-derivatives-to-functions-in-dymola/ , this is also covered in https://specification.modelica.org/v3.4/Ch12.html#declaring-derivatives-of-functions

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately that means modifying the ExternalMedia library, and possibly implementing such derivatives in the underlying CoolProp C++-code. (Brings back memories of my Master's Thesis where I implemented Automatic/Algebraic Differentiation for C++.)

Comment: @user2024223 Thank you, sir,this method seems a bit complicated because I define many functions, but I'll try it first

Comment: @Hans Olsson thank you sir,This is beyond my means.